# Cron job to halt for 30 minutes

Tags: cron, cronexpression

I am trying to set up a cron job which runs every 10 minutes but should stop for exact 30 minutes (miss three runs) between 12:15 to 12:45 (should not run for 12:20, 12:30, 12:40), as some other job will run during this period which might conflict with this one.

Is it possible to achieve this in one cron job expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your cronjob expression is like

```
*/10 * * * * job
```

In that case: No, it is not possible to do so in one cron job expression.

What you can do is to put a condition in your script that checks the time first thing and exits if it is within {12.15 - 12.45} interval.

Otherwise, you'd better change it to:

```
0,10,50 0 * * * job
*/10 1-23 * * * job
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the question at first, no, that can't be done with one job expression.

See also man 5 crontab on your system.

Comment: If we assume the cronjob runs every 10 minutes it means it runs from 00.00 to 23.50. Or at least that's what I understand from the question.

Comment: right @fedorqui, but I am trying to make it run from 0.0 to 0.15 then from 0.45 to 23.50